# Horizontal menu bar not hover submenu in IE11

Tags: html, css

I have created horizontal menu bar but on mouse hover it's not showing the submenu, it's working perfectly in Google Chrome but on Internet Explorer 11 it's not working.
**Note**
I am using Struts2 text property.

**The Code:**

```css
#example {
  width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
  z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #366b82;
}
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute; 
  border-right: 1px solid #54879d; 
}
.navbar li {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center; 
  list-style: none;  
  font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #366b82;
}
.navbar a {       
  padding: 18px 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #54879d;
  border-right: 1px solid #1f5065;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
  background-color: #54879d;
} 
.navbar li ul {
  display: none;
  height: auto;         
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}    
.navbar li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;  
  display: block;
}
.navbar li ul li {
  background-color: #54879d;
} 
.navbar li ul li a  {
  border-left: 1px solid #1f5065; 
  border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; 
  border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065; 
}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

## JSP Page

```
<div id="example">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="Menu1"><s:text name="Menu1"></s:text></a></li>
    <li><a href="Menu2"><s:text name="Menu2"></s:text></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="SubMenu1"><s:text name="SubMenu1"></s:text></a></li>
        <li><a href="SubMenu2"><s:text name="SubMenu2"></s:text></a></li>
         <li><a href="SubMenu3"><s:text name="SubMenu3"></s:text></a></li>
      </ul>         
    </li>       
        <li><a href="#"><s:text name="Menu3"></s:text></a></li>       
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is anything I left or I missed which is applicable on Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Thanks @sebastianbrosch for editing question allow it to run.I dont know that feature.Thanks Again

Comment: this works on IE 11 https://jsfiddle.net/69q5fp6e/

Comment: @DipaliVasani, you are right given jsfiddle is working on IE11...but in my code its not.in actual this jsp page I included as a Header.jsp and I am not able to track whether other css overlaping this but still for avoiding this I have created unique id and class element css but no luck..and same code working in GoogleChrom or Firefox.do you have any idea on which case this can happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,issue is with IE compatability

I Have added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in HTML page and its start working!!